# Creating a document in Java

Tags: java, xml, kml, xmldocument

I am creating a KML document in Java. Inside of it i have to add many similar elements, resulting in the need to add a function, where I can pass needed arguments.

The problem is that when I try to add a part of the document into the main document it shows error, or creates malformed document.
Here's a code snippet:

```
Element style = doc.createElement("Style");
style.setAttribute("id", "green");
dnode.appendChild(style);
Element polyStyle = doc.createElement("PolyStyle");
style.appendChild(polyStyle);
Element color = doc.createElement("color");
color.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("5014F064"));
polyStyle.appendChild(color);
Element iconStyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
style.appendChild(iconStyle);
color = doc.createElement("color");
color.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("5014F064"));
iconStyle.appendChild(color);
```

Element "dnode" is a Document element inside xml. I want to try something like this:

```
doc.appendChild(addFeatureStyle("red", "501400FA"));
```

Called three times with different parameters but have no idea how to include it. I want to add function written above, calling the code snippet.

Should the function "addFeatureStyle" return element, or a string, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try to answer:

> Should the function "addFeatureStyle" return element, or a string, or something else?

You're calling the method `appendChild()` with the value returned by `addFeatureStyle("red", "501400FA")` as argument.

The [documentation of appendChild()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) shows that it takes a Node as argument. So the return type of `addFeatureStyle()` can't be a String:  String doesn't implement the Node interface. The return type of `addFeatureStyle()` must be `Node`, or a class implementing `Node`, or an interface extending `Node`.

Comment: So with the return type of Element, should appendChild accept it or not?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html: it says: *All Superinterfaces: Node* So Element extends Node, so Element is a Node. So yes, of course, you can call appendChild() with an Element as argument.

Comment: Yes, when I received the Element it worked! Solved :)